# Proving $(1+\sec x+\tan x)(1+\csc x+\cot x) = 2(1+\tan x+\cot x+\sec x+\csc x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having some trouble proving this trig identity, I want to prove that:

> $$(1+\sec x+\tan x)(1+\csc x+\cot x) = 2(1+\tan x+\cot x+\sec x+\csc x)$$

Sadly I am stuck.

Comment: I'd write everything in terms of sin and cos, and then simplify the difference of the two sides....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos{x}}+\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin{x}}+\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}\right)=2\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin{x}\cos{x}}+\frac{1}{\sin{x}}+\frac{1}{\cos{x}}\right)$$ or
$$(\sin{x}+\cos{x}+1)^2=2(\sin{x}\cos{x}+\sin{x}+\cos{x}+1)$$ or
$$2+2\sin{x}\cos{x}+2\sin{x}+2\cos{x}=2(\sin{x}\cos{x}+\sin{x}+\cos{x}+1),$$
which is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

expanding the left-hand side we get
$$1+\csc \left( x \right) +\cot \left( x \right) +\sec \left( x \right) 
+\sec \left( x \right) \csc \left( x \right) +\sec \left( x \right) 
\cot \left( x \right) +\tan \left( x \right) +\tan \left( x \right) 
\csc \left( x \right) +\tan \left( x \right) \cot \left( x \right) 
$$ can you simplify this?